# CUPS doesn't even load filters

Tags: cups

I am having a problem with CUPS in an embedded system that seems to be a bit unusual.  CUPS refuses to use filters.  I'm not getting the standard "filter failed" message, it never even attempts to use them.  I have verified my mime types configs and everything, and am printing to a network printer that cups can see and connect to (I can print raw data).  I have even copied the config from my working system over, and can still print raw data, but anything beyond that I get

```
lp: Unsupported document-format "application/pdf".
```

And the logs show a client-error-document-format-not-supported for Send-Document message.  On the working system, I see that it loads some filters to handle processing the file, but nothing is shown on the embedded system's logs.  The filters don't fail, it appears that CUPS never even tries them.

I have the cups-filter package installed, as well as ghostscript, poppler, etc.  Any idea what I could be doing wrong?  A critical compile option I'm missing, or some sort of glue I don't have yet?  If it matters, I am building packages for this system with yocto, but I can try manual cross-compiles if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Posting answer for anyone else who may run into this in the future.  The problem was that cups and cups-filters disagreed on the cups ServerBin directory.  In my case, by default, cups wanted /usr/libexec/cups and cups-filters wanted to use /usr/lib/cups.  Getting them both using the same directory solved my issue.